# $\lim_{n\to \infty}{(\int_{0}^{1}{(f(t))^ndt})^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}{f(x)}$ for Riemann integrals without using Lebesgue

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

I know how to prove this result using Lebesgue integral. But I want to know if someone knows a proof that works for Riemann integral. I know that we can translate the problem into a Lebesgue Integral problem, but I can't use that kind of tools in this course (Calculus I).

Prove that if $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function. Then:

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}{\left(\int_{0}^{1}{(f(t))^ndt}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}}=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}{f(x)}$

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to have $f \ge 0$, otherwise this is wrong. Anyway, in that case let $M$ be the maximum of $f$ on $[0,1]$, and since $f \le M$ you immediately get that
$$ \left( \int_0^1 f(t)^n \, dt \right)^{1/n} \le M $$
for all $n$. If $M=0$, this shows the claim. Otherwise, for any $m \in (0,M)$ there exists an interval $I=(a,b)$ with $a<b$ on which $f(x) > m$, by continuity. Then
$$ \left( \int_0^1 f(t)^n \, dt \right)^{1/n} \ge \left( \int_a^b m^n \, dt \right)^{1/n} \ge  (b-a)^{1/n} m \to m$$
as $n \to \infty$. Since $m$ was arbitrary in $(0,M)$, this show that the limit of the expression exists and equals $M$.